Bluefield-2 NVMe-oF Target Offloading received IB Backend ctrl event: XRQ NVMF backend ctrl timeout error (22)
I'm trying to build the NVMe-oF Target offloading environment based on the Bluefield-2.
I installed the MLNX OFED driver MLNX_OFED_LINUX-23.10-2.1.3.1-rhel7.9-x86_64. The OS version is Centos 7.2009 and the kernel version is 6.0.10.
I followed the steps in the following website:
https://enterprise-support.nvidia.com/s/article/howto-configure-nvme-over-fabrics--nvme-of--target-offload
When I connect to the Target, I will receive the error info in the dmesg of the Target server:
received IB Backend ctrl event: XRQ NVMF backend ctrl timeout error (22)
And I can't use fio read or write the block device /dev/nvme2n1.
FIO will print the following message:
[root@k8s-node3 randread]# fio 4k-rand-r-qd128-6numjobs.config 
test: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=128
...
fio-3.7
Starting 6 processes
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=115801505792, buflen=4096
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=1421357064192, buflen=4096
fio: pid=5779, err=95/file:io_u.c:1747, func=io_u error, error=Operation not supported
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=167814012928, buflen=4096
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=1427328159744, buflen=4096
fio: pid=5783, err=95/file:io_u.c:1747, func=io_u error, error=Operation not supported
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=1465976410112, buflen=4096
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=1338877808640, buflen=4096
fio: pid=5784, err=95/file:io_u.c:1747, func=io_u error, error=Operation not supported
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=1252726947840, buflen=4096
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=1409161920512, buflen=4096
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=489187487744, buflen=4096
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=348755009536, buflen=4096
fio: pid=5782, err=95/file:io_u.c:1747, func=io_u error, error=Operation not supported
fio: pid=5780, err=95/file:io_u.c:1747, func=io_u error, error=Operation not supported
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=188397432832, buflen=4096
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Operation not supported: read offset=1572508553216, buflen=4096
fio: pid=5781, err=95/file:io_u.c:1747, func=io_u error, error=Operation not supported

test: (groupid=0, jobs=6): err=95 (file:io_u.c:1747, func=io_u error, error=Operation not supported): pid=5779: Mon Apr  8 10:32:29 2024
  cpu          : usr=91.18%, sys=5.88%, ctx=27, majf=0, minf=855
  IO depths    : 1=0.8%, 2=1.6%, 4=3.1%, 8=6.2%, 16=12.5%, 32=25.0%, >=64=50.8%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=768,0,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=128

Run status group 0 (all jobs):

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme2n1: ios=0/0, merge=0/0, ticks=0/0, in_queue=0, util=0.00%


In the Target side, I do the following steps:
modprobe -r nvme
modprobe nvme num_p2p_queues=24

# start
mkdir /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testsubsystem
echo 1 \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testsubsystem/attr_allow_any_host
echo 1 \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testsubsystem/attr_offload
mkdir /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testsubsystem/namespaces/1
echo -n /dev/nvme0n1 \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testsubsystem/namespaces/1/device_path
echo 1 \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testsubsystem/namespaces/1/enable

# create nvmet port
mkdir /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1
echo 4420 \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/addr_trsvcid
echo 192.168.1.101 \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/addr_traddr
echo "rdma" \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/addr_trtype
echo "ipv4" \> /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/addr_adrfam
# enable port

ln -s /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testsubsystem/ /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems/testsubsystem

And in the Host side, I do these steps:
modprobe nvme
modprobe nvme-rdma
nvme connect -t rdma -n testsubsystem -a 192.168.1.100 -s 4420

Then I can see the block device /dev/nvme2n1 in the host side. But after several seconds the dmesg in the Target side will print the debug info:
[  743.528042] nvmet: creating nvm controller 1 for subsystem testsubsystem for NQN nqn.2014-08.org.nvmexpress:uuid:a067be64-6f53-4b5f-a780-4a088f99ec84.
[  751.154941] nvmet_rdma: using dynamic staging buffer 0000000072e3e2f8
[  751.219387] nvmet: Adding offload ctx 0 to configfs
[  769.852202] nvme 0000:b2:00.0: received IB Backend ctrl event: XRQ NVMF backend ctrl timeout error (22) be_ctrl 000000002f8cb549 id 0
[  769.852240] nvmet: Removing offload ctx 0 from configfs

I tried update the firmware of the BF2 and reset the configuration of BF2 but nothing changed.
The configuration of BF2 is as follows:
\[root@k8s-node2 jason\]# mlxconfig -d 86:00.0 q

Device #1:
----------

Device type:        BlueField2          
Name:               MBF2H516A-CEEO_Ax   
Description:        BlueField-2 SmartNIC 100GbE Dual-Port QSFP56; PCIe Gen4 x16; Crypto; 16GB on-board DDR; 1GbE OOB management; FHHL
Device:             86:00.0             

Configurations:                                          Next Boot
        MEMIC_BAR_SIZE                              0                   
        MEMIC_SIZE_LIMIT                            _256KB(1)           
        HOST_CHAINING_MODE                          DISABLED(0)         
        HOST_CHAINING_CACHE_DISABLE                 False(0)            
        HOST_CHAINING_DESCRIPTORS                   Array[0..7]         
        HOST_CHAINING_TOTAL_BUFFER_SIZE             Array[0..7]         
        INTERNAL_CPU_MODEL                          SEPARATED_HOST(0)   
        FLEX_PARSER_PROFILE_ENABLE                  0                   
        PROG_PARSE_GRAPH                            False(0)            
        FLEX_IPV4_OVER_VXLAN_PORT                   0                   
        ROCE_NEXT_PROTOCOL                          254                 
        ESWITCH_HAIRPIN_DESCRIPTORS                 Array[0..7]         
        ESWITCH_HAIRPIN_TOT_BUFFER_SIZE             Array[0..7]         
        PF_BAR2_SIZE                                3                   
        DPU_RESET_NOTIFICATION_ENABLED              ENABLED(1)          
        INTERNAL_CPU_RSHIM                          ENABLED(0)          
        PF_NUM_OF_VF_VALID                          False(0)            
        NON_PREFETCHABLE_PF_BAR                     False(0)            
        VF_VPD_ENABLE                               False(0)            
        PF_NUM_PF_MSIX_VALID                        False(0)            
        PER_PF_NUM_SF                               False(0)            
        STRICT_VF_MSIX_NUM                          False(0)            
        VF_NODNIC_ENABLE                            False(0)            
        NUM_PF_MSIX_VALID                           True(1)             
        NUM_OF_VFS                                  16                  
        NUM_OF_PF                                   2                   
        PF_BAR2_ENABLE                              True(1)             
        HIDE_PORT2_PF                               False(0)            
        SRIOV_EN                                    True(1)             
        PF_LOG_BAR_SIZE                             5                   
        VF_LOG_BAR_SIZE                             1                   
        NUM_PF_MSIX                                 63                  
        NUM_VF_MSIX                                 11                  
        INT_LOG_MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE                    AUTOMATIC(0)        
        PCIE_CREDIT_TOKEN_TIMEOUT                   0                   
        RT_PPS_ENABLED_ON_POWERUP                   False(0)            
        LAG_RESOURCE_ALLOCATION                     DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        PHY_COUNT_LINK_UP_DELAY                     DELAY_NONE(0)       
        ACCURATE_TX_SCHEDULER                       False(0)            
        PARTIAL_RESET_EN                            False(0)            
        RESET_WITH_HOST_ON_ERRORS                   False(0)            
        NVME_EMULATION_ENABLE                       False(0)            
        NVME_EMULATION_NUM_VF                       0                   
        NVME_EMULATION_NUM_PF                       1                   
        NVME_EMULATION_VENDOR_ID                    5555                
        NVME_EMULATION_DEVICE_ID                    24577               
        NVME_EMULATION_CLASS_CODE                   67586               
        NVME_EMULATION_REVISION_ID                  0                   
        NVME_EMULATION_SUBSYSTEM_VENDOR_ID          0                   
        NVME_EMULATION_SUBSYSTEM_ID                 0                   
        NVME_EMULATION_NUM_MSIX                     0                   
        NVME_EMULATION_MAX_QUEUE_DEPTH              0                   
        PCI_SWITCH_EMULATION_NUM_PORT               0                   
        VIRTIO_EMULATION_HOTPLUG_TRANS              False(0)            
        PCI_SWITCH_EMULATION_ENABLE                 False(0)            
        VIRTIO_NET_EMULATION_VF_PCI_LAYOUT          VIRTIO_1_X(0)       
        VIRTIO_NET_EMULATION_PF_PCI_LAYOUT          VIRTIO_1_X(0)       
        VIRTIO_NET_EMULATION_ENABLE                 False(0)            
        VIRTIO_NET_EMULATION_NUM_VF                 0                   
        VIRTIO_NET_EMULATION_NUM_PF                 0                   
        VIRTIO_NET_EMU_SUBSYSTEM_VENDOR_ID          6900                
        VIRTIO_NET_EMULATION_SUBSYSTEM_ID           4161                
        VIRTIO_NET_EMULATION_NUM_MSIX               2                   
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMULATION_VF_PCI_LAYOUT          VIRTIO_1_X(0)       
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMULATION_PF_PCI_LAYOUT          VIRTIO_1_X(0)       
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMULATION_ENABLE                 False(0)            
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMULATION_NUM_VF                 0                   
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMULATION_NUM_PF                 0                   
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMU_SUBSYSTEM_VENDOR_ID          6900                
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMULATION_SUBSYSTEM_ID           4162                
        VIRTIO_BLK_EMULATION_NUM_MSIX               2                   
        PCI_DOWNSTREAM_PORT_OWNER                   Array[0..15]        
 RO     HOST_PRIV_RSHIM                             DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        CQE_COMPRESSION                             BALANCED(0)         
        IP_OVER_VXLAN_EN                            False(0)            
        MKEY_BY_NAME                                False(0)            
        PRIO_TAG_REQUIRED_EN                        False(0)            
        UCTX_EN                                     True(1)             
        REAL_TIME_CLOCK_ENABLE                      False(0)            
        RDMA_SELECTIVE_REPEAT_EN                    False(0)            
        PCI_ATOMIC_MODE                             PCI_ATOMIC_DISABLED_EXT_ATOMIC_ENABLED(0)
        TUNNEL_ECN_COPY_DISABLE                     False(0)            
        LRO_LOG_TIMEOUT0                            6                   
        LRO_LOG_TIMEOUT1                            7                   
        LRO_LOG_TIMEOUT2                            8                   
        LRO_LOG_TIMEOUT3                            13                  
        LOG_TX_PSN_WINDOW                           7                   
        VF_MIGRATION_MODE                           DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        LOG_MAX_OUTSTANDING_WQE                     7                   
        ROCE_ADAPTIVE_ROUTING_EN                    False(0)            
        TUNNEL_IP_PROTO_ENTROPY_DISABLE             False(0)            
        USER_PROGRAMMABLE_CC                        False(0)            
        PCC_INT_NP_RTT_DSCP                         26                  
        PCC_INT_NP_RTT_DSCP_EN                      False(0)            
        PCC_INT_NP_RTT_DATA_MODE                    RTT_V0(64)          
        PCC_INT_EN                                  False(0)            
        PCC_INT_SYSTEM_RTT                          0                   
        STEERING_CACHE_REFRESH                      0                   
        MULTI_PCI_RESOURCE_SHARING                  DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        ICM_CACHE_MODE                              DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        HAIRPIN_DATA_BUFFER_LOCK                    False(0)            
        TLS_OPTIMIZE                                False(0)            
        TX_SCHEDULER_BURST                          0                   
        ZERO_TOUCH_TUNING_ENABLE                    False(0)            
        ROCE_CC_LEGACY_DCQCN                        False(0)            
        LOG_MAX_QUEUE                               17                  
        UPT_EMULATION_ENABLE                        False(0)            
        LARGE_MTU_TWEAK_64                          False(0)            
        AES_XTS_TWEAK_INC_64                        False(0)            
        CRYPTO_POLICY                               UNRESTRICTED(1)     
        RDE_DISABLE                                 False(0)            
        PLDM_FW_UPDATE_DISABLE                      False(0)            
        RBT_DISABLE                                 False(0)            
        PCIE_SMBUS_DISABLE                          False(0)            
        PCIE_IN_BAND_VDM_DISABLE                    False(0)            
 RO     HOST_PRIV_NV_HOST                           DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
 RO     HOST_PRIV_NV_PORT                           DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
 RO     HOST_PRIV_NV_GLOBAL                         DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
 RO     HOST_PRIV_NV_INTERNAL_CPU                   DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
 RO     HOST_PRIV_FW_UPDATE                         DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
 RO     HOST_PRIV_NIC_RESET                         DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        LOG_DCR_HASH_TABLE_SIZE                     11                  
        MAX_PACKET_LIFETIME                         0                   
        DCR_LIFO_SIZE                               16384               
        ROCE_CC_PRIO_MASK_P1                        255                 
        ROCE_CC_PRIO_MASK_P2                        255                 
        CLAMP_TGT_RATE_AFTER_TIME_INC_P1            True(1)             
        CLAMP_TGT_RATE_P1                           False(0)            
        RPG_TIME_RESET_P1                           300                 
        RPG_BYTE_RESET_P1                           32767               
        RPG_THRESHOLD_P1                            1                   
        RPG_MAX_RATE_P1                             0                   
        RPG_AI_RATE_P1                              5                   
        RPG_HAI_RATE_P1                             50                  
        RPG_GD_P1                                   11                  
        RPG_MIN_DEC_FAC_P1                          50                  
        RPG_MIN_RATE_P1                             1                   
        RATE_TO_SET_ON_FIRST_CNP_P1                 0                   
        DCE_TCP_G_P1                                1019                
        DCE_TCP_RTT_P1                              1                   
        RATE_REDUCE_MONITOR_PERIOD_P1               4                   
        INITIAL_ALPHA_VALUE_P1                      1023                
        MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_CNPS_P1                    4                   
        CNP_802P_PRIO_P1                            6                   
        CNP_DSCP_P1                                 48                  
        CLAMP_TGT_RATE_AFTER_TIME_INC_P2            True(1)             
        CLAMP_TGT_RATE_P2                           False(0)            
        RPG_TIME_RESET_P2                           300                 
        RPG_BYTE_RESET_P2                           32767               
        RPG_THRESHOLD_P2                            1                   
        RPG_MAX_RATE_P2                             0                   
        RPG_AI_RATE_P2                              5                   
        RPG_HAI_RATE_P2                             50                  
        RPG_GD_P2                                   11                  
        RPG_MIN_DEC_FAC_P2                          50                  
        RPG_MIN_RATE_P2                             1                   
        RATE_TO_SET_ON_FIRST_CNP_P2                 0                   
        DCE_TCP_G_P2                                1019                
        DCE_TCP_RTT_P2                              1                   
        RATE_REDUCE_MONITOR_PERIOD_P2               4                   
        INITIAL_ALPHA_VALUE_P2                      1023                
        MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_CNPS_P2                    4                   
        CNP_802P_PRIO_P2                            6                   
        CNP_DSCP_P2                                 48                  
        LLDP_NB_DCBX_P1                             False(0)            
        LLDP_NB_RX_MODE_P1                          OFF(0)              
        LLDP_NB_TX_MODE_P1                          OFF(0)              
        LLDP_NB_DCBX_P2                             False(0)            
        LLDP_NB_RX_MODE_P2                          OFF(0)              
        LLDP_NB_TX_MODE_P2                          OFF(0)              
        ROCE_RTT_RESP_DSCP_P1                       0                   
        ROCE_RTT_RESP_DSCP_MODE_P1                  DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        ROCE_RTT_RESP_DSCP_P2                       0                   
        ROCE_RTT_RESP_DSCP_MODE_P2                  DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        DCBX_IEEE_P1                                True(1)             
        DCBX_CEE_P1                                 True(1)             
        DCBX_WILLING_P1                             True(1)             
        DCBX_IEEE_P2                                True(1)             
        DCBX_CEE_P2                                 True(1)             
        DCBX_WILLING_P2                             True(1)             
        KEEP_ETH_LINK_UP_P1                         True(1)             
        KEEP_IB_LINK_UP_P1                          False(0)            
        KEEP_LINK_UP_ON_BOOT_P1                     False(0)            
        KEEP_LINK_UP_ON_STANDBY_P1                  False(0)            
        DO_NOT_CLEAR_PORT_STATS_P1                  False(0)            
        AUTO_POWER_SAVE_LINK_DOWN_P1                False(0)            
        KEEP_ETH_LINK_UP_P2                         True(1)             
        KEEP_IB_LINK_UP_P2                          False(0)            
        KEEP_LINK_UP_ON_BOOT_P2                     False(0)            
        KEEP_LINK_UP_ON_STANDBY_P2                  False(0)            
        DO_NOT_CLEAR_PORT_STATS_P2                  False(0)            
        AUTO_POWER_SAVE_LINK_DOWN_P2                False(0)            
        NUM_OF_VL_P1                                _4_VLs(3)           
        NUM_OF_TC_P1                                _8_TCs(0)           
        NUM_OF_PFC_P1                               8                   
        VL15_BUFFER_SIZE_P1                         0                   
        QOS_TRUST_STATE_P1                          TRUST_PCP(1)        
        ETS_SCHED_MODE_P1                           device_default(0)   
        NUM_OF_VL_P2                                _4_VLs(3)           
        NUM_OF_TC_P2                                _8_TCs(0)           
        NUM_OF_PFC_P2                               8                   
        VL15_BUFFER_SIZE_P2                         0                   
        QOS_TRUST_STATE_P2                          TRUST_PCP(1)        
        ETS_SCHED_MODE_P2                           device_default(0)   
        DUP_MAC_ACTION_P1                           LAST_CFG(0)         
        MPFS_MC_LOOPBACK_DISABLE_P1                 False(0)            
        MPFS_UC_LOOPBACK_DISABLE_P1                 False(0)            
        UNKNOWN_UPLINK_MAC_FLOOD_P1                 False(0)            
        SRIOV_IB_ROUTING_MODE_P1                    LID(1)              
        IB_ROUTING_MODE_P1                          LID(1)              
        DUP_MAC_ACTION_P2                           LAST_CFG(0)         
        MPFS_MC_LOOPBACK_DISABLE_P2                 False(0)            
        MPFS_UC_LOOPBACK_DISABLE_P2                 False(0)            
        UNKNOWN_UPLINK_MAC_FLOOD_P2                 False(0)            
        SRIOV_IB_ROUTING_MODE_P2                    LID(1)              
        IB_ROUTING_MODE_P2                          LID(1)              
        PHY_AUTO_NEG_P1                             DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        PHY_RATE_MASK_OVERRIDE_P1                   False(0)            
        PHY_FEC_OVERRIDE_P1                         DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        PHY_AUTO_NEG_P2                             DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        PHY_RATE_MASK_OVERRIDE_P2                   False(0)            
        PHY_FEC_OVERRIDE_P2                         DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        PF_TOTAL_SF                                 0                   
        PF_DEVICE_ID_ENABLE                         False(0)            
        PF_SF_BAR_SIZE                              0                   
        PF_NUM_PF_MSIX                              63                  
        PF_DEVICE_ID                                41686               
        SILENT_MODE                                 False(0)            
        MKEY_BY_NAME_RANGE                          DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        ROCE_CONTROL                                ROCE_ENABLE(2)      
        PCI_WR_ORDERING                             per_mkey(0)         
        MULTI_PORT_VHCA_EN                          False(0)            
        PORT_OWNER                                  True(1)             
        ALLOW_RD_COUNTERS                           True(1)             
        RENEG_ON_CHANGE                             True(1)             
        TRACER_ENABLE                               True(1)             
        IP_VER                                      IPv4(0)             
        BOOT_UNDI_NETWORK_WAIT                      0                   
        UEFI_HII_EN                                 True(1)             
        BOOT_DBG_LOG                                False(0)            
        UEFI_LOGS                                   DISABLED(0)         
        BOOT_VLAN                                   1                   
        LEGACY_BOOT_PROTOCOL                        PXE(1)              
        BOOT_INTERRUPT_DIS                          False(0)            
        BOOT_LACP_DIS                               True(1)             
        BOOT_VLAN_EN                                False(0)            
        BOOT_PKEY                                   0                   
        P2P_ORDERING_MODE                           DEVICE_DEFAULT(0)   
        EXP_ROM_VIRTIO_NET_PXE_ENABLE               True(1)             
        EXP_ROM_VIRTIO_NET_UEFI_ARM_ENABLE          True(1)             
        EXP_ROM_VIRTIO_NET_UEFI_x86_ENABLE          True(1)             
        EXP_ROM_VIRTIO_BLK_UEFI_ARM_ENABLE          True(1)             
        EXP_ROM_VIRTIO_BLK_UEFI_x86_ENABLE          True(1)             
        EXP_ROM_NVME_UEFI_x86_ENABLE                True(1)             
        ATS_ENABLED                                 False(0)            
        DYNAMIC_VF_MSIX_TABLE                       False(0)            
        EXP_ROM_UEFI_ARM_ENABLE                     True(1)             
        EXP_ROM_UEFI_x86_ENABLE                     True(1)             
        EXP_ROM_PXE_ENABLE                          True(1)             
        ADVANCED_PCI_SETTINGS                       False(0)            
        SAFE_MODE_THRESHOLD                         10                  
        SAFE_MODE_ENABLE                            True(1)             

The 'RO' shows parameters which are for read only and cannot be changed

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!
I tried update the firmware of the BF2 and reset the configuration of BF2 but nothing changed.
I also tried other version of MLNX OFED drivers (5.5) and tried the whole processes in another machine but the problem still exists.

I solved this problem through turn off the IOMMU of the server.
vim /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto spectre_v2=retpoline rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet intel_iommu=off"
Then execute grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg and reboot now.
